classical schemes as derived schemes are set valued still
classical scheme can be considered as sheaf through 'functor of points', and when we consider 'sheaf valued in $Spc$ ' on the infinity category $SCRing$ with certain topos, we have the notion of derived stack. Every note I read says 'classical scheme can also be viewed as a derived stack.'
Let's start with the affine case:
$\textbf{Question}$: So this means the mapping space $Map_{SCRing}(A,S)$ is automatically discrete when $S$ is discrete for any simplicial ring $A$? Any categorical explanation for this?
For instance, for the group scheme $GL_{n}$ if viewed as a derived stack, what is its value $GL_{n}(A)$ on the derived affine scheme $Spec(A)$ with $A$ a simplicial ring?
Remark: here is my attempt on this through the Dold-Kan correspondence on the chain complex, if we regard the simplicial ring $A$ as a connective chain complex in $Ch_{\geq 0}(A)$ and $S$ is concentrated in zero. Then the mapping space $Map(A,S)$ (see remark 13.1 in stable infinite category by Lurie) is constructed from the chain complex $[A,S]$ where $[A,S]_{n}=\prod_{m}Hom(A_{m},S_{m+n})$, which is nonzero only when $m=-n$, so if $n$ is positive, and $m$ is negative, then $A_{m}=0$. Thus the only nontrivial term occurs in  nonpositive part, and after composition with a truncated functor which is the right adjoint of the inclusion $Ch_{\geq 0}\rightarrow Ch$, the chain complex we get is concentrated in zero. Thus corresponds to a discrete simplicial ring by Dold-Kan correspondence.
Is this correct and is there any other way to see this?

Shouldn’t it just factor through $\pi_0(A)$?

So you mean when we take the classical scheme $Spec(S)$ as a space valued sheaf on the SCRing, we first take $\pi_{0}(A)$ then output the set valued $Hom(\pi_{0}(A),S)$?. Is this the definition of the embedding of classical scheme into derived scheme? Because as I can see, there is also a natural definition of classical affine scheme $Spec(S)$ as derived scheme by taking the space value on $A\in SCRing$ as the mapping space $Map(A,S)$?

Answered on MO (my previous comment mixed up which direction the morphisms go): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/475677/classical-schemes-as-derived-schemes-are-discrete-valued
